# recursive ctypes structure accesing

Tags: python, c

```
class flistStruct(ctypes.Structure): 
    """This is repos struct which is used in c code"""
    pass
flistStruct._fields_ = [('fname', ctypes.c_char * 257),
            ('ftime', ctypes.c_char * 257),
            ('fsize', ctypes.c_double),
            ('next1',ctypes.POINTER(flistStruct))]
repolistfun.DirRepository.argtypes = [ctypes.c_char_p,ctypes.POINTER(flistStruct)]
        repolistfun.DirRepository.restype = ctypes.c_int

def func():
    mylist = flistStruct()
    ret2 = repolistfun.DirRepository(bytes(arg1, encoding='utf8'),ctypes.byref(mylist))
    while mylist != None:
        result += "fname:"+str(mylist.fname)
        result += "ftime:"+str(mylist.ftime)
        result += "fsize:"+str(mylist.fsize)
        mylist = mylist.next1
```

For the first iteration of while loop, I am getting the values of fname,ftime,fsize.
but for second iteration , I am getting the below error.
error. 'LP_flistStruct' object has no attribute 'fname'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no recursive structures in C, what you've got there as a member is a **pointer to a structure**. You can dereference the pointer simply by using

```
mylist = mylist.next1.contents
```

However, notice that your `mylist != None` is bogus. No ctype will *ever* equal to `None` like that.

Instead you need to restructure your loop as

```
while True:
    result += "fname:"+str(mylist.fname)
    result += "ftime:"+str(mylist.ftime)
    result += "fsize:"+str(mylist.fsize)
    if not mylist.next1:
        break

    mylist = mylist.next1.contents
```

---

Lastly some stylistic advice: your variable naming is off - mylist is not a list but a node/element in the list. And `"fsize:"+str(mylist.fsize)` seems very contrived to write, how about

```
results = []

    ...
    results.append(f"fname:{node.fname} ftime:{node.ftime} fsize:{node.size}")

result = " ".join(results)
```